# @font-face loading time

Tags: wordpress, loading, font-face

I just finished the development of a website where I use @font-face for both H tag and body text...

http://www.futuremobilitynow.org/

The page loading time is fine however the text only appears after few seconds.

What could I do to avoid this ? It there a way of caching the font ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Jk_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't think it has anything to do with the loading of the font.
Seems like your JS is all loaded in the `header` (and some in the `body` as well), resulting in it loading before your `body`. Try putting it in the footer, that way everything else will be loaded before the JS and should show up earlyer.